# Transpiler errors in Babel

Tags: ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs, systemjs, jspm

I recently wanted to switch from browserify but I see this error on Chrome  47 and Firefox 43:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable!module.exports.require.getIterator
 @ core.get-iterator.js:7(anonymous function)
 @ index.js:173(anonymous function)
 @ index.js:196J
 @ system.src.js:4703d.execute
 @ system.src.js:4703i
 @ system.src.js:4703s
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ system.src.js:4703a
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ context.js:9(anonymous function)
 @ context.js:168(anonymous function)
 @ context.js:170J
 @ system.src.js:4703d.execute
 @ system.src.js:4703i
 @ system.src.js:4703s
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ system.src.js:4703a
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ index.js:10(anonymous function)
 @ index.js:192J
 @ system.src.js:4703d.execute
 @ system.src.js:4703i
 @ system.src.js:4703s
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ system.src.js:4703a
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ babel-traverse@6.3.24.js:1(anonymous function)
 @ babel-traverse@6.3.24.js:2J
 @ system.src.js:4703d.execute
 @ system.src.js:4703i
 @ system.src.js:4703s
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ system.src.js:4703a
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ converters.js:25(anonymous function)
 @ converters.js:282J
 @ system.src.js:4703d.execute
 @ system.src.js:4703i
 @ system.src.js:4703s
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ system.src.js:4703a
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ index.js:388(anonymous function)
 @ index.js:393J
 @ system.src.js:4703d.execute
 @ system.src.js:4703i
 @ system.src.js:4703s
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ system.src.js:4703a
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ babel-types@6.3.24.js:1(anonymous function)
 @ babel-types@6.3.24.js:2J
 @ system.src.js:4703d.execute
 @ system.src.js:4703i
 @ system.src.js:4703s
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ system.src.js:4703a
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ node.js:17(anonymous function)
 @ node.js:74J
 @ system.src.js:4703d.execute
 @ system.src.js:4703i
 @ system.src.js:4703s
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ system.src.js:4703a
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ index.js:2(anonymous function)
 @ index.js:4J
 @ system.src.js:4703d.execute
 @ system.src.js:4703i
 @ system.src.js:4703s
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ system.src.js:4703a
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ babel-core@6.3.21.js:1(anonymous function)
 @ babel-core@6.3.21.js:2J
 @ system.src.js:4703d.execute
 @ system.src.js:4703i
 @ system.src.js:4703n
 @ system.src.js:4703execute
 @ system.src.js:4703y
 @ system.src.js:4703w
 @ system.src.js:4703p
 @ system.src.js:4703h
 @ system.src.js:4703(anonymous function)
 @ system.src.js:4703
```

This in my index.html:

```
  <script src="/js/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/config.js"></script>
  <script>
      System.import('/js/main.js');
  </script>
```

I followed the documentation here:
https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/README.md

The main.js has just

> import React from 'react';

Unfortunately, I could not find anything on the web about that issue.

Comment: Well, the error message is quite clear, isn't it? You're iterating over `undefined` somewhere. Without showing us your code and the stack trace of the exception, we hardly can help you more than that though.

Comment: @Bergi The message is not clear at all. It's the babel module, not my code. I updated my post with more information

Comment: @xhitedev That stacktrace contains babel-core.js, babel-traverse.js, node.js, etc... Are you sure you got that error in chrome and firefox? Those libraries usually run during compilation, not at runtime

Comment: @hege_hegedus  systemjs loads each module at runtime in the browser. Not sure whether a polyfill is missing or not